# Can the shelf life of sugar syrup be extended

Tags: sugar, storage, syrup

I prepare natural flavoured sugar syrups, I add glucose (10% of sugar quantity) to covert this sugar into invert sugar so that the syrup doesn’t crystallise. However the shelf life is too short, 2-4 weeks and I see bacteria developing. How to increase the shelf life without using chemical compounds? If I need to add anything as preservative I have decided to add only natural things. Can anyone suggest how to increase the shelf life without changing the taste?

Comment: How do you "see bacteria growing?"

Comment: Do you refrigerate your syrups, or store at room temperature?

Comment: If you see bacteria then it's been unsafe for a lot longer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can extend its life.

Pour the syrup into a freezer bag.

The syrup can last in the freezer for as long as a year.